# Laravel Special Token to Register

Tags: php, laravel

I been trynna make a token system / invite code system for my laravel application but i am having some trobules since im new to laravel.

Anyways this is my RegisterController.php (i am using the default on, but i've added onto it)

```
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'code' => ['required', 'required', 'string', 'exists:codes,code',]
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $usedcode = $data['code'];
        $code = DB::table('codes')->where('code', $usedcode)->first();
        $invby = $code->by;
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'by' => $invby,
        ]);
        $code->user = $usedcode;
        $code->save();
    }
```

As you can see from the above code, currently it does work to validate invite code but the thing is it skips to update the other stuff.

Basically i am trynna make it so after it creates the user it also updates the "codes" table to set the "user" column to the newly registered users ID, and then also trying to update the users table to set the column "by" to the ID that is in the codes table under the column "by"

So all in all, im trynna grab the new users ID, then insert it into users column in "codes" table.

Then i am also trying to grab the "by" column from "codes" to then update it into "users" tables column "by" aswell.

I've tried reforming it, googling and this is my last resort.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `save()` on `$code` since it isn't a reference to a model, it's just a collection retrieved from a table. Try persisting the code data with `DB::insert` or `DB::update`. Alternatively, you could create a Model for your code table.

Comment: Heyo, i do have a model for my codes and i am also including it at the top doing: use App\Codes;

Comment: So instead of `DB::table('codes')->where()`, try `Codes::where` when retrieving your collection.

Comment: Do you also have some tips on validation rules to check if token is unused? Basically in my codes table i got "used" column, and i want to check that the used column is 0

Comment: I tried doing the following: ```        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'code' => ['required', 'string', 'exists:codes,code', Rule::unique('codes')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('used', 0);
        ])``` but it errors syntax error, unexpected ']'